# Conditional routing; choose between two components

Tags: angular

Is it possible to decide which component should we load according to the value of routing parameter? For example:

```
{ path: "address/:id", component: AComponent }
```

I want to load AComponent if `id>3` and BComponent in any other case. Is that feasible and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to third component. And you can dynamically create A or B component in that component.